# Finding out user's second page after visiting homepage in Bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to know which page did users visit after landing on homepage in BigQuery.

Below is the query I figured so far, but the returned result does not align with Google Analytics when I look at the second page (from [Behaviour] --> [Site content] --> [All Pages] --> Primary Dimension: Landing Page, secondary dimension: Second page).

However, the query result matches when I look at Next Pagepath (from [Site Content] --> [All Pages] --> Primary Dimension: Landing Page, Secondary Dimension: Next Page path).

Multiple articles say using [Second page] is more suitable than [Next pagepath].

```sql
-- Total pageviews by pagepath after landing homepage
#standardSQL
SELECT
  next_page.pagePath AS pagePath,
  COUNT(*) as pageviews
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(fullVisitorId, ".", CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS session_id,
      hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
      hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
      hits.type AS type
    FROM
      `GA_data.ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) as hits
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190814'
      AND '20191008'
      AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
      AND hits.page.pagePath = '/***/' -- Landing page URL
      AND hits.isEntrance = TRUE
      AND totals.visits = 1
  ) AS landing_hp
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      CONCAT(fullVisitorId, ".", CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS session_id,
      hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
      hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
      hits.type AS type
    FROM
      `GA_data.ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) as hits
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190814'
      AND '20191008'
      AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
      AND hits.isEntrance IS NULL
      AND totals.visits = 1
  ) AS next_page ON landing_hp.session_id = next_page.session_id
WHERE
  landing_hp.hitNumber < next_page.hitNumber
GROUP BY
  pagePath
ORDER BY
  pageviews DESC
```

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening and what query should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

Your second table does not necessarily return the second page, no? It's also a bit though and inefficient to do it that way with all the joins involved.

It's better to cut all the joins and use sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid -- identify user
  ,visitstarttime -- identify session per user
  -- visitid is timestamp of pre-midnight session
  ,visitstarttime<>visitid AS isMidnightSplitSession 

  -- get hitnumber and pagepath from hits where the type is not event 
  -- limit to one while sorting by hitnumber - offset 1 to get second page
  ,(SELECT AS STRUCT hitnumber, page.pagePath 
     FROM UNNEST(hits) 
     WHERE type<>'EVENT' 
     ORDER BY hitnumber ASC 
     LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS secondPage

  ,(SELECT AS STRUCT hitnumber, page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) 
     WHERE type<>'EVENT' ORDER BY hitnumber ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) AS thirdPage

  -- no need to left join with all those arrays and bloat up the table
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` t 

-- check that first page = '/home'
WHERE (SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE isEntrance=true) = '/home'

  and totals.pageviews>1 -- for testing purpose
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look. 
I would like to see the data granularly so would it be possible to use COUNT(*) by either total pageviews or sessions rather than using visitid?

Comment: I found an article about how to [Replicating The Google Analytics All Pages Report In BigQuery](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/06/01/replicating-google-analytics-all-pages-report-bigquery/), but I am not pretty sure about if is the behavior you expect.